# Vertical Lines in Pinescript v5 Tradingview issue

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I am trying to plot vertical lines on certain dates. The problem statement is I have a start date that I can select using input confirm parameter and have a array of days {5,10,15,20 and so on }. What i need as output is to draw vertical lines on all these days starting from start date.

if start date selected is 1 June, the next vertical line should be on 6 June, next on 11 June and so on

It is just plotting one vertical line on start date, Not sure what I am missing

```
//@version=5
indicator("Vertical lines on Dates", overlay = true)

//interactive start date 
start_date = input.time(timestamp("1 Jul 2021 00:00 +0000"), "Start Date",inline = "01",group = grp1,confirm = true)

// Define the days array
days = array.new_int(21)
array.set(days, 0, 5)
array.set(days, 1, 10)
array.set(days, 2, 15)

for i = 0 to (array.size(days) == 0 ? na : array.size(days) - 1)
    var time_unix=(start_date+array.get(days,i)*86400)
    if time == time_unix
        line.new(time_unix,high,time_unix,low,xloc = xloc.bar_time)
```

Finally based on elod008 input on milliseconds would make it work

```
// Define the days array
days = array.new_int(3)
array.set(days, 0, 5)
array.set(days, 1, 55)
array.set(days, 2, 105)

var lastOccurance_ =start_date
for i = 0 to (array.size(days) == 0 ? na : array.size(days) - 1)
    lastOccurance_ := start_date + array.get(days,i)*60*60*24*1000
    if lastOccurance_ == time
        line.new(bar_index,high * 2,bar_index,low * 0.5,color = color.black)
```

Is there a better way without iterating through array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're missing is pine script time is always in milliseconds and you're adding the seconds value to that which is not meaningful in the calculation.
I suggest you a different approach.
Try to avoid for loops like this for best performance and the proposed solution may also be easier in this specific case than that.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Vertical lines on Dates", overlay = true)

//interactive start date 
start_date = input.time(timestamp("1 Jul 2021 00:00 +0000"), "Start Date",inline = "01",confirm = true)

// if you have strict dates
if start_date <= time and (dayofmonth == 5 or dayofmonth == 10 or dayofmonth == 15)
    line.new(bar_index,high * 2,bar_index,low * 0.5)

// if you use time differences
var lastOccurance = start_date
if start_date <= time
    if lastOccurance + 60*60*24*5*1000 == time
        lastOccurance := time
        line.new(bar_index,high * 2,bar_index,low * 0.5)
```

Comment: Thanks elod008 for your response. The time interval is not fixed but can change. In that scenario what could be a possible approach? Another thing is, I am still not able to get vertical lines with your provided ways. I must be doing something silly looks like

Comment: I've just tested my code again and it prints the lines exactly. I had a problem myself with the newest "confirm=true" input update of tradingview though (linux desktop app) until I figured out that I need to click on a bar to pick a date after having added the indicator so that it starts working. The approach would be still the same. You can easily calculate sg. dynamically and add that in form of a variable to "lastOccurance := nextTimeDiff". Important thing is that it must be in millisecs.

Comment: for fixed internal, it is drawing couple of lines but not able to make it work with non uniform intervals . My problem is my array has more than 30 values, so have to figure some way to do this